# Recursive solution for Pascal's Triangle; just prints output, not in a list

Tags: python, recursion, pascals-triangle

I've been working on a recursive solution to Pascal's Triangle, and I've found a lot of resources/code on how to have the output print as a list. However, I need the output to look like the below:

```
1
1 1
1 2 1
1 3 3 1
1 4 6 4 1
```

etc.

I've been trying to adapt some of the solutions I've seen to output the triangle to lists or nested lists to string so I can achieve the above output, but I am getting stuck. Below is what I have so far, but it only outputs: 1 1

Any help would be appreciated! :)

```
def triangle(n):
    if n == 0:
        return []
    elif n == 1:
        return "1"
    else:
        new_row = "1"
        result = triangle(n-1)
        last_row = result[-1]
        for i in range(len(last_row)-1):
            new_row = ' '.join([last_row[i]], [last_row[i+1]])
        new_row = new_row + "1"
        result = ' '.join(new_row)
    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(triangle(10))
```

Comment: Notice that sometimes `triangle` returns a list, but usually it returns a string.

Comment: Shouldn't you be *adding* pairs of numbers in one row to get the next? Your code will never have any number other than `1`. Also, "I've been trying to adapt some of the solutions I've seen" suggests that you are trying to answer the question by using already existing answers. Why not solve it on your own? A much better learning experience.

Comment: So the first rule of recursive functions is to consider the base case. I must admit, it took me a few goes to get that one right.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things wrong with your code. The first is the base case. There only needs to be one base case where `n==1` and this should return `[[1]]` which is a list containing a list which contains `1`.

The next is that each `new_row` should be a list, so I start it off with `[1]`.

The next is that as you iterate over the previous list you need to add adjacent elements together, ie adding an `int` to an `int` and not concatenating strings.

Lastly, the `new_row` should be appended to the `result` of the previous call to `triangle()`.

Here is the modified code:

```py
def triangle(n):
    if n == 1:
        return [[1]]

    new_row = [1]
    result = triangle(n - 1)
    last_row = result[-1]
    for i in range(len(last_row) - 1):
        new_row.append(last_row[i] + last_row[i + 1])
    new_row.append(1)
    result.append(new_row)
    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for row in triangle(10):
        print(*row)
```

Output:

```
1
1 1
1 2 1
1 3 3 1
1 4 6 4 1
1 5 10 10 5 1
1 6 15 20 15 6 1
1 7 21 35 35 21 7 1
1 8 28 56 70 56 28 8 1
1 9 36 84 126 126 84 36 9 1
```